# SQL Server : creating a new column when a file is imported

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I am trying to load `.csv` files into a SQL Server database using the Import and Export wizard. I need to automatically create a new column `load time` that records the time when the `.csv` file was loaded into the database table.

How would this be possible?

Example

```
col1   col2   col3   load_time
-------------------------------------------------
abc    abc    abc    (time this file was loaded)
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a default value on the column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a DEFAULT constraint on the field with getdate()

e.g.

```
[load_time] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_load_time]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
```

or in SQL Management Studio

[image: Default Value or Binding[1]]

Note: This will only work if you are importing into an existing table and not creating a new one during the import.

Comment: Thank you for a quick response, this helps alot! Similarly, if i wanted to extract everything after a specific character (from a column in the table that was imported) and put it inside the new column automatically, can i use the same method?

Comment: Possibly, but then you would have to write a function that got that value.  The other option would be to use an INSERT TRIGGER